# simple recursive parser using pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

```
exp = Forward()
exp << (Literal('x') ^ (exp + Literal('+') + exp))
exp.parseString('x+x', parseAll = True)
```

This code makes infinite recursion.

```
exp << (Literal('x') ^ ('x' + Literal('+') + exp))
```

If I change it as above, then it works well.
but I want to keep using the current expression. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You have a left-recursive parser - pyparsing does no implicit lookahead, so it will recurse forever, as you have found. Are you trying to write an infix arithmetic notation parser? If so, look at the fourFn.py example to see how this is done, or the `infixNotation` helper method included with pyparsing.